# How can I get this figure's hands to stop exploding when I export this figure as an FBX?

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx, distort

Thank you for stopping by.  I have an FBX file that is giving me problems when I export it from Blender.  I'm bringing it into Blender to work on its textures, which are not displaying correctly.  Before import, the figure looks like this:

[image]

While working with the figure in Blender, it also looks okay, but when I export it as an FBX file, the hands explode:

[image]

The only thing I'm changing is the material zones in Blender, so I imagine it must be a problem with Blender's FBX export.  I have tried adjusting the options in that export dialog, but it hasn't had an effect on this problem.  How do I get this portion of the mesh to stop distorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  I'm not sure of the logic behind it, but I found that the problem went away when I changed Export-->FBX-->Geometry-->Smoothing from "Normals Only" to "Face".